# WKWebView take full page screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

```
takeSnapshot(with: snapshotConfiguration) { (image, error) in
}
```

And

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToSave.contentSize)
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Both Apple provided API **takeSnapshot()** and **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** taking the screenshot of visible area only.

Anyone could tell me how to capture a full page content screenshot of **WKWebView**?